# Java custom separator output for looping

Tags: java, for-loop, output, separator

I've this for loop

```
for(int i=1; i <= bil; i++){
            if (i%2!=0)
            System.out.print(i+" ");
        }
```

and i want an output like this (if bil =5)

```
1, 3 and 5
```

So, how to get this output that have a comma separator and the last loop have different separator like 'and' ?

Comment: Gramatically, it should be "1, 3, and 5". You need the coma after the 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it:

```java
StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
int lastComma = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= bil; i++) {
    if (i % 2 != 0) {
        if (buf.length() != 0) {
            lastComma = buf.length();
            buf.append(", ");
        }
        buf.append(i);
    }
}
if (lastComma != 0)
    buf.replace(lastComma, lastComma + 1, " and");
System.out.print(buf.toString());
```

*Results with various values of `bil`*

```
bil=1   ->  1
bil=2   ->  1
bil=3   ->  1 and 3
bil=4   ->  1 and 3
bil=5   ->  1, 3 and 5
bil=6   ->  1, 3 and 5
bil=7   ->  1, 3, 5 and 7
bil=8   ->  1, 3, 5 and 7
bil=9   ->  1, 3, 5, 7 and 9
bil=10  ->  1, 3, 5, 7 and 9
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
static void printBil(int bil) {
    String separator = "";
    for (int i = 1; i <= bil; i++) {
        if (i % 2 != 0)
            System.out.print(separator + i);
        separator = i + 2 >= bil ? " and " : ", ";
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

and

```
for (int i = 1; i < 10; ++i) {
    System.out.print("bil=" + i + " : ");
    printBil(i);
}
```

output:

```
bil=1 : 1
bil=2 : 1
bil=3 : 1 and 3
bil=4 : 1 and 3
bil=5 : 1, 3 and 5
bil=6 : 1, 3 and 5
bil=7 : 1, 3, 5 and 7
bil=8 : 1, 3, 5 and 7
bil=9 : 1, 3, 5, 7 and 9
```

Answer (score 0):

Try.

```
var sj = new StringJoiner(", ", "", "");
String tmp = null;
for (int i = 1; i <= bil; i++) {
    if (i % 2 != 0) {
        if (tmp != null) {
            sj.add(tmp);
        }
        tmp = Integer.toString(i);
    }
}
var res = sj.length() > 0
        ? sj.toString() + " and " + tmp
        : sj.add(tmp).toString();
System.out.println(res);
```

Result:

```
bil=1   ➡️  1
bil=2   ➡️  1
bil=3   ➡️  1 and 3
bil=4   ➡️  1 and 3
bil=5   ➡️  1, 3 and 5
bil=6   ➡️  1, 3 and 5
bil=7   ➡️  1, 3, 5 and 7
bil=8   ➡️  1, 3, 5 and 7
bil=9   ➡️  1, 3, 5, 7 and 9
bil=10  ➡️  1, 3, 5, 7 and 9
```

Comment: According to this [survey](https://snyk.io/wp-content/uploads/jvm_2020.pdf), 2 in 3 developers use Java 8 which means they are probably not familiar with the **var** keyword that was introduced in Java 10. Besides which, what benefit does it provide in the code you posted, apart from letting you type a few less characters? Or are you merely trying to demonstrate its use?

Comment: try to demonstrate  I don't think that the most developer use which `Java 8` at work aren't  familiar with new features.